# get deobfuscation file in GP console if not use proguard?

Tags: android-studio, proguard

I do not use proguard, but google in Google Play Developer Console asks for the proguard deobfuscation file to see a detailed error log.

I tried looking for build / outputs / release / mapping / mapping.txt but it’s empty here, generally there is no mapping folder. I also tried to search by searching and the mapping.txt file is nowhere to be found. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

In your `app/build.gradle` file, you must enable obfuscation by setting `minifyEnabled` to true.

```
buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled true
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

After that, when you make release build, you should be able to see generated mapping file in `app/build/outputs/release/mapping` directory.

Comment: I have not minifyEnabled, but Proguard require proguard file .